# Android textinput where the user can write digits and '/'

Tags: android, android-inputtype

My user has to enter a string like `21/99` where digits and the sign `/` are the only valid signs that the user can enter, ideally those would all be shown on the keyboard and little other signs. 
Unfortunately, neither `number` nor `text` not any other type I found produces in such an UI.
Is there a way where I can make it easy for my user to enter such numbers.

Comment: hope this will help you

https://github.com/santalu/mask-edittext
https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext
https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh : While the solution provided here is the same as in the other answers that are linked as doublicate the issue itself isn't. The fact that I'm focused on a specific set of characters that I want to be entered with the UI leaves the possibility open for an UI solution that only shows the user the relevant characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`android:digits="1234567890/"`** in **`EditText`**

> [**`android:digits`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits)

- If set, specifies that this TextView has a numeric input method and that these specific characters are the ones that it will accept. If this is set

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:digits="1234567890/"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```